# What's the best way to specify an unknown index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

I'm pulling data from Google sheets with this:

```
for x in range(0, 3):
    gmap.marker(latitude[x], longitude[x], title=boxnumber[x])
```

There are only three values in each column to pull. So, the above code works well. However, if I have four like this:

```
for x in range(0, 4):
```

I get List index out of range... The problem is, I don't know what my second number/list index will be. This number may be 25 tomorrow, or maybe 60. What's the best way to deal with this? For example, if I have 50 in my list, how can I get the for loop to call 50 automatically?  Is there a way to call (0, #ofavailable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `enumerate()`:

```
for x,y in enumerate(latitude):
    gmap.marker(latitude[x], longitude[x], title=boxnumber[x])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `len()` to get the length of the lists (I assume they're all the same length).

```
for x in range(len(latitude)):
    gmap.marker(latitude[x], longitude[x], title=boxnumber[x])
```

Or zip all the lists together:

```
for lat, lon, title in zip(latitude, longitude, boxnumber):
    gmap.marker(lat, lon, title=title)
```

You should also consider putting everything into a single list of dictionaries or tuples, rather than separate lists for each value.

Answer (score 1):

You could do len(list), which would give the length of your list. You could also, instead of `for x in range(0, len(list)):`, just do `for x in list:` which would give you the item at each index, instead of just the index, if that's simpler for your project.